# Torus in a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be a n-dimensional torus and $M\subseteq \mathbb{T}^n$ be a submanifold homoemorphic to $\mathbb{T}^n$. Do we have necessarily have $M=\mathbb{T}^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since the dimension of $M$ is $n$, $M$ is open in $\mathbb{T}^n$, it is also closed since it is compact, since $\mathbb{T}^n$ is connected, $M=\mathbb{T}^n$.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that approach as well, but missed to note that same dimension implies open.

Comment: @Tsemo: if we replace $T^n$ with $R^n$ the OP statement does not hold anymore. The key point is the compactness of $T^n$ right?

Comment: @magma It's compactness and connected. You could consider $M:=\{ 0 \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n+1} \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $\{ 0\} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n+2} \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, the later is homemorphic to $M$ and $M$ is compact. For $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\neq 0$) we can consider an open nonempty ball, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.